# How SharedPreferences with UpdateUI?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am a noob on developing android apps. I want to ask. How my PreferenceActivity want to Update without back to MainActivity and goto PreferenceActivity again. In this, i give some feature to change the Theme of PreferenceActivity. This is my PreferenceActivity:

public class SettingsPreference extends PreferenceActivity
{

```
SwitchPreference themeSwitch;
String myPref = "preferences";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String summary;
int theme;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(myPref, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(myPref, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    final String summary = prefs.getString("stringSummary", "Default theme");
    final int theme = prefs.getInt("intTheme", (android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light));   

    setTheme(theme);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preference);

    themeSwitch = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("switchTheme");
    themeSwitch.setSummary(summary);

    if (themeSwitch != null) {
        themeSwitch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object isOnObject) {
                    boolean isThemeOn = (Boolean) isOnObject;
                    if (isThemeOn) {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsPreference.this, "Theme Dark ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editor.putString("stringSummary", "Theme Dark ON");
                        editor.putInt("intTheme", (android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault));
                        editor.apply();
                        themeSwitch.setSummary(summary);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsPreference.this, "Theme Dark OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        editor.putString("stringSummary", "Theme Dark OFF");
                        editor.putInt("intTheme", (android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light));
                        editor.apply();
                        themeSwitch.setSummary(summary);

                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the Activity layout you just have to restart it.
Try to add this at the end of onPreferenceChange().

if you're in API11+, call in an Activity.

```
this.recreate();
```

Otherwise, we just have to finish the activity and start it again with the same intent.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have update every 20 seconds for example , This is code :

```
 import android.os.Handler;

    Handler handler  = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //update UI
        }
    },2000);
```

Put this in a function and re-call in run .